# Boto3 Upload_file - TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

Im trying to do a simple upload of a .txt file with a few lines in it.
I have used AWS' own example, but getting an error. I have searched for a few hours and tried 5-6 different upload methodes, all giving the same error message. What am I missing?

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
filename = 'file.txt' bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
s3.upload_file(filename, bucket_name, filename)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this was me being stupid..

I had my bucket defind as

```
bucket_name = s3.Bucket('hs-sftp-abc-shopping-sto')
```

And the upload function as

```
s3.upload_file(filename, bucket_name, filename)
```

But the bucket name should just be a string, and not a `s3.bucket()`.

FML :-)